# React Native - Parent View to wrap the child view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have a view having text inside it. The component looks like this:

```js
MyComponent = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>My Text</Text>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = {
    viewStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#006699',
        height: 40,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    textStyle: {
        color: '#000000',
        fontSize: 16,
    }
}
```

When this component gets used, I want my View to have a custom width such that it just wraps my text. Here's the visual clue:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's about the original design of [Layout with Flexbox](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html).

You can make it work by either add `flexDirection: 'row'` to it's parent view (so it will stretch automatically related to `<Text />` width),

```js
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>My Text</Text>
  </View>                
</View>
```

or give width to it directly.

```js
<View style=[{styles.viewStyle}, {width: 50}]>
  <Text style={styles.textStyle}>My Text</Text>
</View>
```

**Result of option 1:**

[image]